# Count of a column and sum of another in the same groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'delivery_date' : ['2018-09-07' ,'2018-09-07','2018-09-08','2018-09-09','2018-09-10'],
              'user' : ['user1','user1','user2','user3','user3'],
             'number_of_papers' : [3,4,3,2,4]})
```

I want to do a group by `delivery_date` and `user`. Where:

- Finds `count` of times a `user` has delivered something in a day.
- Finds `sum` of `number_of_papers`

I used `.agg` but I don't think it applies here because the `count` and `sum` are about different columns.

```
df.groupby(['delivery_date','user'])['delivery_date'].agg(['count','sum']).sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False,True]).reset_index(name ='Counts')
```

> Error TypeError: reduction operation 'sum' not allowed for this dtype

The sum should be for `number_of_papers`. I don't know where to write this in groupby.

Example:
This does all except the `sum` part:

```
a.groupby(['delivery_date','user'])['delivery_date'].count().sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False,True]).reset_index(name ='counts')
```

gives:

```
delivery_date   user    counts
0   2018-09-10  user3   1
1   2018-09-09  user3   1
2   2018-09-08  user2   1
3   2018-09-07  user1   2
```

I simply want to also do the `sum` of `number_of_papers` in this table as a new column called `sum`.

Comment: I tihnk you're just referencing the wrong column in your first groupby statement. use `number_of_papers` instead. ie `df.groupby(['delivery_date','user'])['number_of_papers'].agg(['count','sum']).sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False,True]).reset_index()` works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary in [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html#pandas-dataframe-aggregate) function for specific computation related to column then `rename` the columns and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['delivery_date','user']).agg({'delivery_date':'count','number_of_papers':'sum'}).\
                                     sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[False,True]).\
                                     rename(columns={'delivery_date':'count','number_of_papers':'sum'}).\
                                     reset_index()

    delivery_date   user    count   sum
0   2018-09-10      user3   1       4
1   2018-09-09      user3   1       2
2   2018-09-08      user2   1       3
3   2018-09-07      user1   2       7
```

Comment: We can declare what column each calculation is about using it in the `.agg`  with a dictionary?

Comment: @user10389994 yes that is what I did. Check the link provided in answer.

Comment: In another dataset where the number_of_papers is float64 I get : `TypeError: reduction operation 'sum' not allowed for this dtype
`

Comment: @user10389994 It will work for `float64` double check the dtype. I tested it worked. If you want to try just replace `number_of_papers` with `[3.,4.0,3.,2.,4.]` and try my solution. It works.

Comment: `using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`

Comment: @user10389994 After `groupby` directly use `agg` function without accessing any `columns`, like how I used in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use agg this way

[image]

```
    df.groupby(['delivery_date', 'user'])['number_of_papers'].agg('sum')
```

Comment: Where is the count ?

Comment: I believe you will get it this way